# determine os architecture and bitness in java

Tags: java, dynamic, architecture, operating-system

I want to be able to dynamically determine the OS, architecture, and bit-ness in my Java application.

For example, I would like my application to know when it is on a Solaris 32-bit sparc machine or when it is on a x86 machine.

I know the system get property returns the arch of the JVM, but is there any  to truly find out the real os arch and bit-ness?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? One of Java's primary raisons d'être is shielding you from such things...

Comment: I added some functionality that makes use of external libraries, but those libraries are OS dependent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to get the byte order is to use ByteOrder.nativeOrder();

The OS is in the system properties.

To determine if the JVM is 64-bit I use the following taken from ehcache.

```
private static final boolean IS64BIT = is64Bit0();

public static boolean is64Bit() {
    return IS64BIT;
}

private static boolean is64Bit0() {
    String systemProp;
    systemProp = System.getProperty("com.ibm.vm.bitmode");
    if (systemProp != null) {
        return systemProp.equals("64");
    }
    systemProp = System.getProperty("sun.arch.data.model");
    if (systemProp != null) {
        return systemProp.equals("64");
    }
    systemProp = System.getProperty("java.vm.version");
    return systemProp != null && systemProp.contains("_64");
}
```

Comment: thank you so much. didn't think about checking endian-ness. very helpful.

Comment: @Seephor Usually it's best to write code where you don't need to know this sort of things.

Comment: I agree, but I had to make use of some external libraries that are platform dependent.